# std::function std::bind with lambda overload ambiguity

Tags: c++, function, lambda, std

Consider the following code

```
class my_class {
public:
struct my_struct {
   int i;
};
std::function<void(my_struct&)> func;
my_class() {
   func = std::bind([this](my_struct& s) { s.i = 5; });
}
};
```

On VS 2017 I am receiving the following errors:

error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'std::_Binder>' to 'std::function'
note: No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous

Any thoughts on what I'm missing to resolve the ambiguity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is about the most unhelpful compiler error ever. The problem is that you want

```
func = std::bind([this](my_struct& s) { s.i = 5; }, std::placeholders::_1);
//                                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

`std::bind(f)` means "give me a `g` such that `g(/* anything */)` is `f()`.

You need to use placeholders if you want to pass arguments through.

(I assume that your real code does something more complicated than this, because there's no need for `bind` or for capturing `this` in the code you've shown.)

Answer (score 2):

`std::bind` is more or less obsolete in C++11. Just use a lambda instead.

```
class my_class
{
public:
  struct my_struct {
    int i;
  };
  my_class()
  : func ([](my_struct& s) { s.i = 5; }) {}
private:
  std::function<void(my_struct&)> func;
};
```

Comment: You mean C++14. You still need `std::bind` to support moving stuff into the lambda's context in C++11 instead of copying.

Comment: @StoryTeller In C++11 it's *almost* obsolete (I said *more or less*). In C++14 it's even more (completely?) obsolete.

Comment: I don't think one can say it's obsolete in any measure if there's a use case that actually requires it. But perhaps I'm just splitting hairs. It most definitely has virtually no use in C++14.